# How can I solve the Ramanujan problem by using Wolfram language?

Tags: programming, procedural-programming

The problem like this:
find all integers n, 1 ≤ n ≤ 10, 000 such that n is the sum of two cubes of positive integers in two different ways.
I want to solve the problem as a procedure in mathematica.

Comment: What have you tried? I would be nice if you post your code even if it is not fully working. By the way, the second number is the taxicab number `Ta(2)` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number

Comment: Check `FindInstance`.

Comment: @yarchik I write a C code first, and I try to translate it into wolfram language, but the console tells me that it has too many recursioni times(over 1000), my C code is like define 8 variables, and use 4 layers for loops to do the calculation, (first layer loop from 1 to 10000, and check the first variable(ac=a*a*a) greater than 10000 or not, then enter the second layer of for loop, to check bc=b*b*b, bc+ac>=10000 or not, then until I get all the variables.) the c code working well, but since im a fresh man on mathematica, the wolfram code not working.

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {n == a^3 + b^3, n == c^3 + d^3, 1 <= n <= 10000, a >= b > 0, 
   a > c >= d > 0};

sol = Solve[eqns, {n, a, b, c, d}, Integers]

(* {{n -> 1729, a -> 12, b -> 1, c -> 10, d -> 9}, {n -> 4104, a -> 16, 
  b -> 2, c -> 15, d -> 9}} *)

And @@ Flatten[eqns /. sol]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, this does not check there are exactly two solutions, but the smallest number that is the sum of two cubes in three different ways is 87,539,319, so it's safe here.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut - the OP does not require that the number not be expressible as the sum of three cubes, i.e., it does not say "**only** two different ways."

Comment: Interesting. I tend to understand such a sentence as "exactly two". My bad. Anyway, for those interested: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaxicabNumber.html, and of course https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(number)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `IntegerPartitions` to find integers representable as the sum of two cubes.

```
Table[
   {n, IntegerPartitions[n, {2}, Range[n]^3]},
   {n, 1, 100}]
```

Also, `PowersRepresentations` is designed for problems like this; however, it uses non-negative integers, allowing 0 as one of the cubes.

```
Table[
   {n, PowersRepresentations[n, 2, 3]},
   {n, 1, 100}]
```

For "Taxicab Numbers", make a table of representations and select integers with more than one solution. Check that no solution uses 0.

```
Select[
   Table[
      {n, PowersRepresentations[n, 2, 3]},
      {n, 1, 10000}],
   Length[#[[2]]] >= 2 &]
```

> {{1729, {{1, 12}, {9, 10}}}, {4104, {{2, 16}, {9, 15}}}}